# Multiply numbers among themselves

Tags: c++

I want to build the following program:

The user has to insert a number between 100 and 999 (like `100 < i < 999`) and the numbers have to be multiplied among themselves.
Example:

- A Valid Input: 178
- Corresponding Result: 1*7*8 = 72

I tried to achieve the first part i.e. checking for the number given as input to be within 100 and 999 in the two ways below, but my approach isn't said to be elegant:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char n[4];    
    scanf("%s", n);
    printf("%d\n", (n[0]-'0')*(n[1]-'0')*(n[2]-'0'));
    return 0;
}
```

or

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int array[3];
    scanf("%1d%1d%1d", &array[0],&array[1],&array[2]);
    for ( int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }        
    return 0;
}
```

Are they any better ways to achieve the same?

I'm looking for a C++ solution.

Comment: To clarify, state a specific problem which you are trying to solve. If your code works incorrectly, specify the circumstances (user input), what it does and what you want it to do. If you don't know how to implement a feature, specify what the feature is, and delete everything not related to it.

Comment: `int n; scanf(" %d", &n);`? Or even better, use iostream: `int n; std::cin >> n;`. Validate the number *after* reading it.

Comment: Oh, people said that this way to answer a question like this is not elegant. Thats because I´m trying to get another way to have the final result...

Comment: It would be more elegant if you would put it through a code formatter ;) But jokes aside, both of them are C, the first one is _really_ unsafe (it relies on the user entering exactly 3 digits), but seems to do what you want and the second doesn't really do anything. If you want to write this in C++ you'll have to start all over again.

Comment: Isn't said to be elegant.. by whom?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings A kind of programmers in my country where I asked first the question. I´m happy here. Very helpful the people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can impose `std::cin` as a conditional in a while:

```cpp
int x;
while (std::cin >> x && x>=100 && x <=999)
\\ Do what you want
```

For multiplying the digits, simply extract each digit by getting its remainder when divided by 10, multiply that with the current product (set a variable, with inital value 1) then divide by 10 subsequently in a loop till you get the product of all digits. For example, create a function which returns the product of digits of a number:

```cpp
int digitproduct(int x) 
{  int product = 1;
   while (x != 0)   
   {
        product *= (n % 10);
        x /= 10; 
    } 
    return product; 
}
```

Call that inside the while:

```cpp
int x;
while (std::cin >> x && x>=100 && x <=999)
{   cout<< digitproduct(x);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much. This helped completely. I will add to my folders and will create new functions to exercise.

Comment: @Cordas Anytime. I am trying to get your question re-opened since it was valid on the pretext of what you wanted. (the product of digits of a number between 100 and 999) You gave two approaches for the input part, which shows a bit of effort. This should not be closed. Upvoted as well.

Comment: Yes, its my first time here. I´m learning how that works. What that means? That this case is closed and nobody can add infos?

Comment: @Cordas Yes, once a question is closed, it cannot be answered anew, or have any new answers other than the existing ones. For more information, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0):

People may say, your solution isn't elegant, because it does not easily scales if you may want to add more digest or remove some.
The first one will also have a buffer overflow as soon the user enters more than 4 characters!
But out of my option I like the second one quite much, because it shows a much better understanding of C than just reading the number via `int n; std::cin >> n;`, validating it, and then calculating the result.

But there is a small flaw as well, you need to check the return value of `scanf` in order to detect if a number has been successfully parsed or not.

```
int res = scanf("%1d%1d%1d", &array[0],&array[1],&array[2]);
if(res != 3) {
   printf("Invalid number format. Expected a three digit number, but got %d", res);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More elegant solution will be to obtain the number as an integer and then decompose it to the single digits with division and modulo operations.

This greatly increases the ability to validate the input number and knowing how to decompose the integer may be useful if the number is not given as a string, but from other parts of the program as a number.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);

    if(number > 999 || number < 100) {
        printf("Number not in range\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("%d\n",
            (number / 100) *        // hundreds digit
            (number / 10 % 10) *    // tens digit
            (number % 10)           // units digit
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Thats a second way to do that. For what shoud I been prepared in the future? Do I have to elaborate many solutions or only one? Because I see that always any have a different solution...Not only for this kind of problem, but in general sense